# How do you get ML performance metrics using the Youden index in the tidymodels framework?

Tags: r, performance, machine-learning, tidymodels

How do you get ML performance metrics using the Youden index in the tidymodels framework?

I have search for examples online, but I haven't found any.

Answer (score 0):

The metrics for the tidymodels framework are in the [yardstick](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/) package. If you search there for "Youden", you'll land at the page for [Youden's J statistic](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/j_index.html), `j_index()`.